# Missing application on android nougat play store

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I have an application that I have deployed to play store which I set compatibility to android v 4.1 and up.

But I just realize that it not shown on android N play store search application (I still don't check on android O version)

is some permission / compatibility change on android nougat? Because it still shown on android M play store. I have tried to search on play store web and it is still there.

Thanks.

NB: I build this application using ionic v1 framework

Comment: I have less knowledge about using ionic. However if there is a manifest file, can you share that? It can be an issue with `<uses-feature` in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution by contact the Google using Live Chat on developer console.

it appears that i need to compiled and build again using android sdk version 25 that support android Nougat 7.1.1 because
this problem arise for android Nougat version 7.1.0+ and not for version below it